# language learning on ubuntu tablet

Tags: application-development

I have a linux computer, but i use an android tablet. On my tablet i have a series of apps for learning french and spanish. My favorites are the "fun easy learn" apps which lets you memorize words. But i also use apps to help with verb conjugation. My question is this: will there be more language learning apps in the ubutnu app store for tablets?

My other uses for the tablet are listening to podcasts and radio, and watching netflix. I dot not write longer texts on the tablet.

For the phone, my favorite feature is the hotspot function which lets me use the phone as a router. Call blocking and recording conversations are essential because of the many telemarketers.

Answer (score -1):

For language learning, I have found [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) very useful, which works on a variety of platforms, including Ubuntu. It is based on a technique called `spaced repetition` and, although not the best exponent of "fun" it is definitely "easy learn".

It works for many other fields, not just languages.

Comment: Thanks, i have encountered the anki app, but i couldn't find it in the ubuntu tablet app store. Anki is ok, it's sort of a simpler version of the "fun easy learn" apps. But it takes up enormous amounts of space. It wouldn't take much work to adapt the fun easy learn apps to ubuntu, i think. I have mailed the developers and asked them. Writing isn't the best use of a tablet, but it is excellent for learning because you hold it up to your face, like book. Reading comics is another great use for a tablet, and ebooks of course.